# How to suppress notifications in SPSS

Tags: syntax, notifications, spss

I want to write a syntax to automatically compute monthly collected data with the same structure. I have written the syntax but there are some notifications (no error warnings), which I have to close manually.

Is it possible to prevent SPSS from popping up these notifications?

Edit: Here is what the message says (I am using SPSS in German, so I have to translate it): "Die following Pivot-tables contain a very long line labeling. The tables can not be wrapped and will be scaled down to fit on the page. You can edit the tables manually, to narrow the line labelings." The only button is the OK-Button.

Comment: SPSS seldom produces pop-up notifications. You may want to describe these pop-up error in more detail and perhaps any syntax that is appropriate in generating these pop-ups.

Comment: I edited the question